# Object in grid is visible when outside of grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create spectogram.
I created grid and I generate pictures out of values and I'm moving pictures from above outside of grid to grid. Problem is that object outside of grid is visible, when it is part of grid.
How can I solve that?

XAML grid with rectangle inside

```
 <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="453" Margin="246,462,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1463" Background="Black">
            <Rectangle Fill="Pink" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="176" Margin="310,-92,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
```

[Image of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD7yY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ClipToBounds to true
[ClipToBounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)